# woocommerce_thankyou hook not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

When I paste the code below directly into the `thankyou.php`, it works perfectly fine. but when I try to hook it into `woocommerce_thankyou`, nothing happens.

I'm just getting started with PHP,

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'test_1', 10, 1);

function test_1() {
    $paymethod = $order->payment_method_title;
    $orderstat = $order->get_status();

    if (($orderstat == 'completed') && ($paymethod == 'PayPal')) {
        echo "something";
    } elseif (($orderstat == 'processing') && ($paymethod == 'PayPal')) {
        echo "some other shit";
    } elseif (($orderstat == 'pending') && ($paymethod == 'PayPal')) {
        echo "some other shit";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `hook`?

Comment: how you try to hook it into?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> First of all you have to add the function and hook in `functions.php`
> file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin PHP
> files. Secondly you need to create an instance/object of order, to
> access the data.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'wh_test_1', 10, 1);

function wh_test_1($order_id) { //<--check this line

    //create an order instance
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id); //<--check this line

    $paymethod = $order->payment_method_title;
    $orderstat = $order->get_status();

    if (($orderstat == 'completed') && ($paymethod == 'PayPal')) {
        echo "something";
    } 
    elseif (($orderstat == 'processing') && ($paymethod == 'PayPal')) {

        echo "some other code";
    } 
    elseif (($orderstat == 'pending') && ($paymethod == 'PayPal')) {
        echo "some other code";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @HeinrichHeld my guess is that the add_action line specifies that we're taking 1 argument -  add_action(.., .., 10, 1) but your original code test_1() doesn't have it