# Getting the value of the product's id value (_product_id) after the payment in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to get the value of `_product_id` on the payout page (`thankyou.php`),  can somebody help me with this.

I have attached an image of the field I need exactly that value

[image: value into database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use `woocommerce_thankyou` hook to get the product ID's in
> thankyou page

```
function wh_getProductIds($order_id)
{
    //getting order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $product_id_arr = [];
    //getting all line items
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item)
    {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $product_id_arr = $product->get_id(); //storing the product ID
        //$product_sku = $product->get_sku();
    }
    //$product_id_arr has all the order's product IDs
    //now you can do your stuff here.
}

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'wh_getProductIds', 10, 1);
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.** *version `3.x` or above*

Related:

- [Woocommerce Get Orders on Thank you page and pass data javascript snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42313444/5019802)
- [WooCommerce Conversion Tracking Script for two Pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44000977/5019802)
- [woocommerce_thankyou hook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43303436)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, should this code be added to the file (functions.php) only, or do I need to add the same code to the thankyou.php file?

Comment: @srdjan_stojanovic: glad that it helped you, Only add this code to your `functions.php` file.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not succeed, i have entered this code (see link) but there is no change..  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3674ef10efa13a73782347bb89caff11

Comment: @srdjan_stojanovic: what you want to achieve after getting the product ID? If you add this `var_dump($product_id_arr);die('im here, for test');` just before the functions end. and place a order you 'll see that product ID(s) is/are printed.

Comment: Now I get always reuzultat :(NULL im here, for test), I think I'm doing something wrong .. I set up a function and this call all in the file (function.php). is it enough or do I have to do something else?

Comment: @srdjan_stojanovic: I again tested my code and it is working at my end, I think either plugin or any theme not allowing the code to work without priority, I have update my code pls try with that. I changed `add_action`.